# PHP socket connection optimization

Tags: php, sockets, optimization, networking, telnet

I am making this connection with an API that uses telnet, when I run the commands in a shell everything happens faster, however, when I run the commands using php sockets performance drops dramatically. I'm having some code misconceived?

```
/ **  
* Tries to make the connection to the server specified in the constructor, if the connection is made returns TRUE  
* Otherwise FALSE.  
* @Return boolean  
*/  
public function connect() {  

    try {  
        $stream = fsockopen($this->getHost(), $this->getPort(), $errno, $errstr, $this->getTimeOut());  

        $this->setStream($stream);  

        return true;  
    } catch (ErrorException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;  
    } catch (Exception $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;  
    }  
}  

/ **
* Runs the specified command in $command at voipzilla's API through a socket connection.  
* @See $this-> connect ()  
* @Param string $command  
* @Param int $nl number of new lines (Enter) after the command   
* @Param boolean $command Sets the command clause will be added to the specified command  
* @Return string coming API's response API  
* /  
public function runCommand($command, $nl=4, $commandClause=true) {  
        //response  
        $response = null;  
        //
        $login = "login " . $this->getLogin() . "\n";  
        $login .= "password " . $this->getPassword() . "\n\n";  

        if ($commandClause) {  
            $command = "command " . $command;  
        }  

        $command = $login . $command;  

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $nl; $i++) {  
            $command .= "\n";  
        }  

        if(!$this->connect()){exit(0);}  

        fwrite($this->getStream(), $command);  

        while (!feof($this->getStream())) {  
            $response .= fgets($this->getStream(), 128);  
        }  

        return $response;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your code is connecting and authenticating (logging-in) yourself **everytime** a command is issued. So, there are more communications between client and server than in a single SSH session.

**Solution:** Try [`pfsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php) instead of `fsockopen` and don't authenticate everytime. It behaves exactly as `fsockopen()` with the difference that the connection is not closed after the script finishes. It is the persistent version of `fsockopen()`.

Comment: I've tried to authenticate only once, which happens when you try to run a command after authentication, the command is not executed, because the API automatically closes the connection, it should be borne by the interval between authentication and execution of next command (that is long due to the slowness). The way I'm doing now (authenticating every time) works. I used pfsockopen and the slowness continues.